# Document clustering to find common strings in a pandas column

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am building a classification model in order to improve a system. I have converted the resolution strings into recommendation strings using `nltk` library. The problem I am having now is there are many resolution strings that are very common. I want to merge these into a common string. For example, if I had the strings

`It is recommended to replace scanner`
`It is recommended to change scanner`

Then I would take the string that occurs the most in the column which is `It is recommended to replace scanner` and replace `It is recommended to change scanner` with it. I hope that is clear. Since I have many different resolution strings 188,000 or more. I first tried the `fuzzy wuzzy` library but it was much t0o slow.

Now I am trying clustering, at the moment I have tried `kmeans` with `tf-idf` but its not giving me the best results. For example,

```
v = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=6000, ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words = 'english', strip_accents= 'ascii')
x = v.fit_transform(hardware['resolution_modified'])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=30).fit(x)
```

I then test it like this

```
test_strings = ['It is recommended to replace keyboard',
                'It is recommended to change keyboard',
                'It is recommended to replace laptop', 
                'It is recommended to image scanner', 
                'It is recommended to replace defective scanner with new', 
                'It is recommended to replace scanner',
                'It is recommended to change battery']
kmeans.predict(v.transform(test_strings))
```

which gives me this output

```
array([ 5, 27,  8, 25,  3, 11, 27], dtype=int32)
```

As you can see the results are not that good. I have also tried other clustering methods like hierarchical clustering such as `AgglomerativeClustering` but I got memory errors even though I have 122 gb of ram. I know its computationally expensive as well. I have also tried `DBScan` but I do not have much experience with it to gain any meaningful results.

I wanted to see if there is any suggestions as to where I should go from here? Perhaps there are more stable clustering methods for text data or changing some of the parameters in `tf-idf` could yield better results.